# "Special" Moving Average

Tags: python, rolling-computation

I'm trying to calculate a "special" moving average.  The code that I'm trying is based on TradeStation EasyLanguage and calculates Keltner bands but with a twist.  The heart of the code calculates an average true range of price and is as follows:

```
sum = sum + TrueRange
if (CurrentBar >= 20) then
MAverage = sum/20
sum = sum * (19/20)
else
MAverage = sum
```

I can replicate this code with the following python code; however, the execution time is astronomical.

```
# MAverage
tr = df['TR']
    
df['trsum'] = float(0)
trsum = df['trsum']
    
df['Avg Range'] = float(0)
ma = df['Avg Range']
    
trsum[1] = tr[1]
for ii in range(2,samples):
    trsum[ii] = trsum[ii-1] + tr[ii]
    if ii > 19:
        ma[ii] = trsum[ii]/20
        trsum[ii] = trsum[ii] * 19/20`
```

I've also tried to just use a plain old ewa (exponential moving average) but the numbers are a bit further off than what I would like.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Numpy and Numba

As you have discovered, Pandas is not very fast when we iterate over the rows. We should be using methods like
df2['trsum'] = df2['TR'].cumsum(). Unfortunately I also couldn't find a fast way to do it with Pandas so I
just used Numpy. I also tried Numba to speed up execution.

The code below has 3 functions:-

```
sma(df): # This is the code from the question
sma_numpy(df): # This converts the Dataframe to a Numpy Array
sma_numba(df): # This converts the Dataframe to a Numpy Array and uses Numba to JIT compile the function
```

#### Timing results

```
def sma() Pandas: 35.831744300000004s for 100000 rows
def sma_numpy() Numpy: 2.0248809000000065s for 1000000 rows
def sma_numba() Numpy + Numba: 0.05904679999999729s for 1000000 rows
```

As you can see the Numba function is 6000x faster! I could only run the Pandas version with 100000 rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from numba import jit

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000000, 1)), columns=['TR'])


def sma(df):
    # code copied from the question 

    samples = len(df)
    # MAverage
    tr = df['TR']

    df['trsum'] = float(0)
    trsum = df['trsum']

    df['Avg Range'] = float(0)
    ma = df['Avg Range']

    trsum[1] = tr[1]
    for ii in range(2, samples):
        trsum[ii] = trsum[ii - 1] + tr[ii]
        if ii > 19:
            ma[ii] = trsum[ii] / 20
            trsum[ii] = trsum[ii] * 19 / 20

    return df


def sma_numpy(df):
    tr = 0
    trsum = 1
    ma = 2

    samples = len(df)

    df['trsum'] = float(0)
    df['Avg Range'] = float(0)
    npa = df.to_numpy()

    npa[1,1] = npa[1,0]

    for ii in range(2, samples):
        npa[ii,trsum] = npa[ii-1,trsum] + npa[ii,tr]
        if ii > 19:
            npa[ii,ma] = npa[ii,trsum] / 20
            npa[ii, trsum] *= 19 / 20


    return pd.DataFrame(data=npa, columns=df.columns)


@jit(nopython=True)
def sma_numba_loop(npa):
    tr = 0
    trsum = 1
    ma = 2
    samples = len(npa)

    for ii in range(2, samples):
        npa[ii, trsum] = npa[ii - 1, trsum] + npa[ii, tr]
        if ii > 19:
            npa[ii, ma] = npa[ii, trsum] / 20
            npa[ii, trsum] *= 19 / 20


def sma_numba(df):

    df['trsum'] = float(0)
    df['Avg Range'] = float(0)
    npa = df.to_numpy()

    npa[1, 1] = npa[1, 0]

    sma_numba_loop(npa)

    return pd.DataFrame(data=npa, columns=df.columns)


df_small = df[0:100_000].copy()
print(sma_numba(df[0:30].copy())) # JIT compile to save time

print("def sma() Pandas: ", timeit.Timer(lambda: sma(df_small.copy())).timeit(number=1), f's for {len(df_small)} rows', sep='')
print("def sma_numpy() Numpy: ", timeit.Timer(lambda: sma_numpy(df.copy())).timeit(number=1), f's for {len(df)} rows', sep='')
print("def sma_numba() Numpy + Numba: ", timeit.Timer(lambda: sma_numba(df.copy())).timeit(number=1), f's for {len(df)} rows', sep='')

'''
Check a sample to make sure they all return the same values
print(sma(df_small.copy())[10000:10010])
print(sma_numpy(df.copy())[10000:10010])
print(sma_numba(df.copy())[10000:10010])
'''
```